# android. Запись аудио с внешнего динамика и микрофона в один файл

Tags: android, аудио

Добрый день. Задача такова - MediaPlayer проигрывает трек. Можно ли осуществить запись голоса человека вместе с этим треком? Или отдельно записать звук с микрофона (MediaRecorder`ом) а потом как-то наложить на имеющийся трек.

Answer (score 1):

broadcastmyself имеет режим записи в файл, там можно так делать, а еще стримить на shoutcast/icecast.